# Is this an acceptable process in Angular-JS

Tags: angularjs

```
ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.something"
```

Is there a better way to write this? I am inside serval ng-repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have isolated scopes, you should just be able to reference your `something` property directly. Scopes inherit their parent properties.

```
ng-model="something"
```

EDIT: there are some gotchas around this. Take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes